# How can I change the precission of a floating point number in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm

I am currently studying computer sciense and in one of my classes (Computer Arquitecture) i am asked to make a function (in ARM assembly) that shows te result of multipying euler to a power (input). In this question they tell me that the result must be calculated with a precission of 0.001, the thing is, i don't know how to do that. If anyone could show me how it would be much apreciated.

Comment: Normal double precision (64 bit) floating point numbers are precise to 15 decimal digits.  This should be more than enough for the task.  There's no need to “change precision” or anything like that.  Instead, worry about implementing a good algorithm to compute this function.

Comment: ARM doesn't have `e^x` in hardware; you have to implement it yourself with single-precision or double-precision math.  It's up to you to write an accurate enough implementation of the function.  e.g. stuff the right exponent bits into the binary representation, and use an accurate-enough polynomial approximation for the mantissa (to implement 2^x, then scale that).  You can search on SO for SIMD log and exp implementation methods.  (Most of them with x86 SIMD intrinsics, but they do describe the math and ARM uses the same IEEE754 binary FP formats.)

Comment: Note that the well-known Taylor formula for e^x will give very bad results for large negative x, so for x < 0 calculate 1 / e^(-x).

Comment: @gnasher729 A good approach to fix this is to compute 2^y using y = x/log 2.. 
 Normalise y to be in the interval (0.5, 1] and use the appropriate series.  Then scale the result by altering the exponent as needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes i understand that i need to implement the function. The part that i don´t quite understand is how to restrict the number's precission, as i am asked specificaly for a precission of 0.001

Comment: @Bito You don't need to do that.  “must be calculated with a precision of 0.001” means that the value of digits valued less than 0.001 doesn't matter.  It doesn't mean that you actively need to restrict anything.  Simply compute with full precision and use an algorithm that reaches the desired precision.  Having more precision never hurts.

Comment: Like fuz said, "precision of 0.001" means that for any given input, the *maximum* absolute error is 0.001.  (Or the maximum *relative* error is 1 part in 1000, i.e. `|(actual - exact) / exact| <= 0.001`.  Those are different things.)  It doesn't have to be *exactly* 0.001 - achieving that would require computing the exact result and then biasing it by 0.001 or something like that!  (Except that's impossible because 0.001 isn't exactly representable as a binary floating point value)

Comment: Thanks @fuz for clarifying my doubts. Now a can start making this assignment.

Comment: @Bito What is the largest input value?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's an integer entered by standard input, so i hope when they correct this they don't use something too big

Comment: "they tell me that the result must be calculated with an (_absolute_) precision of 0.001" is _not_ a reasonable  goal - it is very difficult to do for x > about 43.  What makes sense is a _relative_ precision.  So is the goal really absolute or the more save relative precision?  (or is the input `x < 43`?)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i'd say the later, but that would be a fuess, because my homewrok assistant is not very... comunicated