# Division in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, division

For an assignment i need to raise a number to a power entered by standard input (i need to work with floating-point numbers). My idea was to make while loops with a counter, and if the integer is negative, to divide 1 by the actual number (like raising it to -1). The thing is, i don't know a way to divide in arm assembly, i have searched but with no luck, the only thing i found is someone vaguely mentioning rotation. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be perfect. I am using ARMSim v5 by the way.

Edit: i compiled a c file with gcc -S and the output threw some errors in ARMSim, which i don't understand why:

```
    .file   "xd.c"
    .text
    .globl  x
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   x, @object
    .size   x, 4
x:
    .long   6
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    x(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    shrl    $31, %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    sarl    %eax
    movl    %eax, x(%rip)
    movl    x(%rip), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Not sure where you looked, the instruction set reference would have been a good place. It lists `VDIV` which is a floating-point divide. For `1/x` you likely want floating point.

Comment: Look at C compiler output for a C implementation of your idea.  You could consider handling negatives by taking the reciprocal of the base, and absolute value of the exponent, then using your standard multiply loop.  (That should perform much better, and only need one loop instead of 2 versions.)

Comment: it is quite common to see a multiply by 1/x even if the ISA has a divide as multiply is faster, and I am talking about fixed point not float, converting to float doing a divide then back is worse than just an integer multiply and maybe a shift.  the other solution is to use the C compilers library gcclib basically for gcc for example.  doing your own long division is pretty straight forward as well if you wish to do that, it is faster than just subtracting in a loop which of course would work.

Comment: If this is the same assignment [as before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60645429/417501) then you should note that this is for floating point numbers.  You should also specify which floating point unit (VFP, NEON, or something else) you are going to use.

Comment: @fuz yes, it is the same assignment. And for the other thing, i don't know much about this topic, as you can see i barely know anything about arm assembly, much less about other kinds of assembly (for exaple mips, i don't know anything about it). But i will add to the question that i am talking about floating point numbers

Comment: @Bito I see.  Please answer the question about what floating point unit you use as there are multiple different standards for floating point units on ARM.

Comment: Normally ARM development kits include optimized software divide function(s) in the provided libraries if the version of ARM doesn't have a divide. I'm thinking you could write a C program that uses a divide, then have the compiler output assembly code and look at the assembly code.

Comment: @rcgldr i tried wyour advise and used gcc -S to compile, but it even throws some errors on ARMSim, i added the output to the question.

Comment: That's x86-64 assembly.  Obviously it won't assemble with an ARM assembler.  Use an ARM compiler.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ or install a package that provides `arm-none-eabi-gcc`

Comment: @PeterCordes - I recall an optimized divide function for ARMV4 that was 150 lines of assembly code. It had two tables, one for quotients < 256, the other to provide the initial estimated quotient of 7 bits, then using hard coded Newton Raphson division algorithm to increase quotient to 28 bits. The calculated quotient equals actual quotient  or actual quotient-1 (a post check is done for this). ARM developer kits should include a divide function, and usually include source code.